# Bounding $x$ given $x^p (1-x)^{1-p}\geq c$

Tags: inequality

I'm working on a project and came across
$x^p (1-x)^{(1-p)} \geq c$.

Here both  $x$ and $p \in [0,1]$.
I need bounds on $x$ but am not being able to get any by plain algebra. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped it at first. The exponent on (1-x) is (1-p) not p.

Comment: Make two cases, $p\geq 1-p$ and $1-p>p$

Answer (score 1):

There is no close formula, excepted in particular cases like $p=1/2$. You can only give qualitative answer. The logarithmic derivative of $f : x \mapsto x^p(1-x)^{1-p}$ on $(0,1)$ is given by
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{p}{x} - \frac{1-p}{1-x} = \frac{p-x}{x(1-x)}.$$
Hence $f$ increases on $[0,p]$ and decreases on $[p,1]$.
If $c \le p^p(1-p)^{1-p}$ (the interesting cases), the solutions of the inequation $f(x) \ge c$ form a closed sub-interval $[a,b]$ of $[0,1]$. The two solutions $a$ and $b$  of the equation $f(x) = c$ can be computed numerically, for example by applying Newton's method to the concave function $\ln f - \ln c$.

Comment: That clears things up. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in Christophe's answer, there is a maximum at $p.$ But also, the function is concave up, so you can get decent bounds by a piecewise linear approximation